.png file failed to compile in C#.NET project (.NET MAUI). Error APT2098
I am testing a .NET MAUI project for mistakes and it failed to compile some images although they live in a similar root directory
orca_composer_divider_horizontal.9.png: Error APT2261 : file failed to compile.

error Error APT2098 : drawable-hdpi-v4_orca_composer_divider_horizontal.9.png.flat: error: failed to open file. "drawable-hdpi-v4_orca_composer_divider_horizontal.9.png.flat: error: failed to open file.".

For example:
the directory net7.0-android\lp\106\jl\res\drawable-hdpi-v4 images non of them work while in the directory net7.0-android\lp\333\jl\res\drawable-hdpi-v4 none of the images report any problem
I don't understand why all the project images work except those in that directory.
I tried to see if images were real PNG in that directory by checking them on a hex editor and they have the correct first eight bytes of a PNG. I also tried to open and see their dimensions but they were similar to the images that worked in all other directories. I also checked their names to make sure they don't have any special symbols (non-ASCII characters) and found no problem here is an example in case I missed something
Image that didn't work name: orca_emoji_category_cars.png
one that worked in the other folder: notification_oversize_large_icon_bg.png

"it failed to compile some images" What does that actually mean? What error did you actually see?

sorry you are correct i edited the question and forgot to add that partError APT2098 : drawable-hdpi-v4_orca_composer_divider_horizontal.9.png.flat: error: failed to open file. "drawable-hdpi-v4_orca_composer_divider_horizontal.9.png.flat: error: failed to open file.".

The error appears to be saying that it cannot open a file called "drawable-hdpi-v4_orca_composer_divider_horizontal.9.png.flat" (Note the .flat file extension.) Have you confirmed that the file actually exists?

it doesn't exist
this is the other error.
the image error: orca_composer_divider_horizontal.9.png: Error APT2261: file failed to compile.
I think they are linked as far as I know the flat file is just a build file and it doesn't exist when compilation fails

Did you see https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-xamarin/issues/19, https://github.com/dotnet/android/issues/7971 and https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/xamarinforms-android-fail-to-build-fresh-created/1390190 which all seem related the length of the file path.

I actually tried shortening the file path before. but only that directory although its depth in the project is the same as the other example i provided but i will check again because it makes sense

thank you. I think this problem was resolved. now i have this issue/error
0>colors.xml(2): Error APT2260 : resource color/white (aka com.DeepSound.Android:color/white) not found
but I think it has nothing to do with the images

Feel free to add your own answer, you can even accept it after 15 minutes IIRC.

The problem was solved by shortening the path leading to the file. The path was longer than the MAUI standard of max 265 characters.

You should accept your own answer to end the discussion.
